How to apply one function to all elements with the same class
I want to click on any of the 3 buttons, and they all will change their background colors at the same time. What is missing or needed to change in my code, for the addEventListener to be able to apply in all elements with the same class?


const one = document.getElementsByClassName('one');

one.forEach((element) => {    
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (element.style.backgroundColor = "#DCDCDC") {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#56F1FF";
      } else {
        element.style.backgroundColor = "#DCDCDC";
      }
     })
 });
.one {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.one:hover {
  background-color: #56F1FF;
}
<button class="one">Catch</button>
<button class="one">Change</button>
<button class="one">Choose</button>




@fpetrakov: please don't change - or approve edits that change - the code in the question. Changing the code of the question into code that works both changes and invalidates the question, and also likely invalidates the existing answers. I've reverted the question to its original form that demonstrates the problem that OP wanted help with.

There are couple of things wrong here.

document.getElementsByClassName returns a HTMLCollection that doesn't have access to forEach method. You have to convert it into an array before using forEach.

element.style.backgroundColor returns a RGB value, you can't compare it with HEX code.


Here is the correct way to fix this
const btnCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('one');
const buttons = Array.from(btnCollection);  // Convert to an array

buttons.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (element.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(220, 220, 220)") {  
            buttons.forEach((btn) => btn.style.backgroundColor = "#56F1FF");  
        } else {
            buttons.forEach((btn) => btn.style.backgroundColor = "#DCDCDC");  
        }
    });
});


The call document.getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object, but not an array. See: MDN - getElementsByClassName
The function forEach can only be called on an array.
To fix this, you need to create an array from the array-like object, which can be achieved by using Array.from. See: MDN - Array.from
Update your JavaScript like this:
const one = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('one'));


As explained .forEach() doesn't exists on HTMLCollection returned from getElementsByClassName.
But I would recommend potentially better approach of using a container:


document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.matches('button') && 
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('alternate-bg');
});
#container button {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

#container button:hover {
  background-color: #56F1FF;
}
#container.alternate-bg button{
  background-color: #56F1FF;
}
<div id="container">
<button>Catch</button>
<button>Change</button>
<button>Choose</button>
</div>



